# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Xcode 15 (Directory not found)

Tags: xcode, react-native, build

I'm getting this error when running my react-native application using Xcode. If I go to the logs it says the following:

`/bin/sh: /Users/me/Desktop/project: No such file or directory`

I know that this isn't the directory of the project it is `/Desktop/folder/project`, but I don't know how to change this. It doesn't even say where to check if it is wrong.